# Is return superfluous after setting handled to true in a KeyPress event?

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

Is the "return" necessary in the code below:

```
if (((e.KeyChar == '1') && (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPterodactylNum1.Text))) ||
    ((e.KeyChar == '2') && (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPterodactylNum2.Text))) ||
    ((e.KeyChar == '3') && (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxPterodactylNum3.Text)))) {
    e.Handled = true;
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format(
        "There is no corresponding value for {0} in the pterodactyl TextBox above", e.KeyChar));
    return;
}
. . .
// other code follows if gauntlet above is passed through safely; don't want to continue if it didn't, though (if handled was set to true)
```

?

Comment: No. if you don't returns it will continue execute code behind the conditional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Handled` property does not stop execution of the event in its tracks, it simply tells bubbled events that you've handled it and no longer want anything else to process. So, the code below your `e.Handled = true` could potentially reverse that to a false state which would allow bubbled  events to continue handling the event.

Answer (score 1):

It is not inherently superfluous. You haven't shown the code that follows, but that code could potentially set `e.Handled = false`.

Comment: e.Handled is never set to False, however I don't want to continue processing needlessly, so thanks all three of youse guise for your unanimous answer.